# Checkboxes NgModel with verifications and get method on update

Tags: angular

I want to pop up browser confirm alert on click but when I press cancel, my unchecked checkbox change, while my method properly is not running.

HTML

```
<input name="related" type="checkbox" [checked]="attr.related (change)="updateOnCheck(i)" [(ngModel)]="attr.related" #related="ngModel" />
```

component

```
updateOnCheck(i: number) {
   this.dataService.update(this.checkrelated).subscribe(res => {.... etc})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
updateOnCheck(i: any) { 
   this.dataService.update(this.checkrelated).subscribe(res => {
    // Your code
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple input without wrapped component use:

you.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  styles: [],
  template: `
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
  `
})
export class YourComponent {
  onCheckboxChange(event: MouseEvent) {
    const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).checked;
    if (value) {
      /// your code
    } else {
      /// another code
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that if i press cancel on window alert the checkbox turn to checked!